# R Plotly: How to use config() in conjunction with plotly_build()?

Tags: javascript, r, plot, plotly

Run the code up to and including `plotly_build(p)` and the correct plot results.

### Reproducible Code

```
library(plotly)

#data
df1 <- data.frame(cond = factor( rep(c("A","B"), each=200) ),
                  rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8)))

df2 <- data.frame(x=c(.5,1),cond=factor(c("A","B")))

#plot
gg <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=rating, fill=cond)) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(rating, na.rm=T))
               , color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1, name="average") +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(rating, na.rm=T))
               , color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1, name="median", yaxt="n") +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, position="dodge")

#create plotly object
p <- plotly_build(gg)

#append additional options to plot object
p$data[[1]]$hoverinfo <- "name+x" #hover options for 'average'
p$data[[2]]$hoverinfo <- "name+x" #hover options for 'median'

#display plot
plotly_build(p)
config(displayModeBar = F, showLink = F) # comment this line/config(.. out to get the plot
```

### Problem

I want to use `config` to change a few settings. However, the use of `config()` seems to override the `hoverinfo` changes.

**Before running config (how the plot should be)...**

[image]

**Then after running `config(displayModeBar = F, showLink = F)`...**

[image]

**Lastly, I tried running config prior to the `hoverinfo` lines:**

```
#create plotly object
p <- plotly_build(gg)
config(p=p,displayModeBar = F, showLink = F) #run config before 'hoverinfo' changes

#append additional options to plot object
p$data[[1]]$hoverinfo <- "name+x" #hover options for 'average'
p$data[[2]]$hoverinfo <- "name+x" #hover options for 'median'

#display plot
plotly_build(p)
```

However, the `config` settings seem to be overridden with the return of the `displayModeBar` (screenshot below):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the last *config* line works for me:

```
p <- plotly_build(gg)

p$data[[1]]$hoverinfo <- "name+x" #hover options for 'average'
p$data[[2]]$hoverinfo <- "name+x" #hover options for 'median'
    
p$config <- list(displayModeBar = F, showLink = F)
```

Derived from the source code.

### Update

As of at least Plotly version 4.5.6, `config` is now a part of the `x` attribute of a Plotly object. The line should read:

```
p$x$config <- list(displayModeBar = F, showLink = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code did not work is because you did not assign the `config` call back to p. `config` invisibly returns a modified plotly object.

ie, this should work fine:

`p <- config(p=p,displayModeBar = F, showLink = F)`